# cannot format 32gb micro sd card in window 10

Tags: formatting, sd-card, format, micro-sd-card

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB     0
  Disk 1    Online           31 GB     0
DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART>create partition primary 

DiskPart succeeded in creating the spectified partition.

DISKPART> active 

DiskPart marked the current partition as  active.

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> format fs=fat32

    0 percent completed

DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken. the size of your disk, exceeds the capability of FAT32.  You can confirm this by simply using Disk Management instead.  Edit your question to include the formatted information from the Event Log.

Comment: @Ramhound - the 320GB in his title is a mistake. His drive is only 32GB, which should be right at the limit of FAT32.

Comment: Still wondering why he is using Diskpart though.  Question should be edited to clarify.

Comment: also, while native windows dosen't support larger sizes, its not a file system limitation [fat32formatter](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm) would work up to 2TB. Its a tool, not an FS limitation. I don't see anything *particularly wrong* with the command. I wonder if NTFS would work here

Comment: Please include the log from the Event Viewer. just search for `eventvwr.msc` in the start menu and under the `Windows Logs` catalog, click on `System`. And look for an error generated by disk part. Please edit the question and insert the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell one of those options

1. Your device is write protected. Maybe check if you have a lock mechanism on the side.
2. Your device is dying. SD cards are flimsy things that like to break if you look at them funny. Or so goes my experience with them.

To be certain, attempt to format it on a linux environment.

Comment: Also, SD cards have a limited amount of write operations. It might be over that limit, which causes weird behaviors.